# How to use .cfg and saving options of a program

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am currently doing a project in vb and I want to have an option form where a user can customize the controls (e.g. importing pictures and labels) and I want it to be saved in an external .cfg or another method. P.S. I am still a newbie at this and I will continue to ask more simple questions as I progress on it project.

Comment: I answered your question, please provide feedback, and mark the answer as accepted/upvote if you find it has answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be wanting to write to `My.Settings` and saving them with `My.Settings.Save`.

First you'll want to *define* your settings in the project's property pages:

[image]

A `user` setting creates new settings for *each user-account* the application is run under, `application` setting makes it so that the settings are *global* and affects everyone regardless of what privileges they hold in the system.

There are also differences to how the settings are saved:

**Application:** Saves in the `[project name].config` file

**User:** Saves in the `<c:\Documents>\<username>\[LocalSettings\]ApplicationData\<companyname>\<appdomainname>_<eid>_<hash>\<version>`

You can [see more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691858/where-are-my-settings-saved-in-vb-2010-net) on where the settings are saved.

Example use-cases:

**Application:**

- License key (***see the 'word of warning' below***)
- Administrative settings (proxy settings, filters, etc)

**User**:

- Username
- Time/Date of last use
- Application colour scheme

In this example I'll use these settings:

[image]

If I wanted to set the setting `Username`, I would want to do:

```
My.Settings.Username = "Test"
```

and to save the settings you would do

```
My.Settings.Save()
```

The output file is `[project name].config`, and the settings stored in it are similar to this:

```
<userSettings>
    <ConsoleApplication1tst.My.MySettings>
        <setting name="PictureLocations" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="Labels" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="Username" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="LastAccessDate" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
    </ConsoleApplication1tst.My.MySettings>
</userSettings>
```

**A word of warning:**

> ***Never*** place passwords or license keys in the application's settings as these can be easily read. If you *have to*, encrypt them first (and *don't* use MD5 for it either!).

More information on `My.Settings` [can be found here.](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/72654-using-settings/)

Comment: Will the settings be saved in another file or is it in the application itself?

Comment: @Zeratul1339 Updated my answer. I don't actually see the `Username` setting that I set as a test when I built an example program in the config file, so perhaps it's stored in the registry. I'll look further into this.

Comment: Will the program generate the .config file?

Comment: @Zeratul1339 Visual Studio generates the file when the project is compiled, and I *think* the program modifies it.

Comment: That should do it. Keep an eye on my profile for my other future questions. I'm sure you can easily answer those.

Comment: @Zeratul1339 Updated my answer with the locations where the two different Scope types `application` and `user` are saved.