# Visual Basic username password error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am creating a vb app for mailing system to send cv through mail quickly .when i create a check box to save my email and password but it give me an error  username and password error in code say username is not a member of window Application

```
    If email.Checked = True Then
        My.Settings.username = usernamebox.Text
        My.Settings.Save()
        My.Settings.Reload()
    End If
    If pass.Checked = True Then
        My.Settings.password = passwordbox.Text
        My.Settings.Save()
        My.Settings.Reload()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Handles MyBase.Load
    usernamebox.Text = My.Settings.username
    passwordbox.Text = My.Settings.password
End Sub
Private Sub Clear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs)
    Handles Clear.Click
    My.Settings.password = passwordbox.Text
    My.Settings.Reset()
    My.Settings.Reload()
    My.Settings.username = usernamebox.Text
    My.Settings.Reset()
    My.Settings.Reload()
    usernamebox.Text = Nothing
    passwordbox.Text = Nothing
End Sub
```

in this code `My.Settings.username` is giving me an error and `My.Settings.password`
and please also guide me how to add BCC(blind carbon copy ) function in vb app....

Comment: Do not post links to external sites. Post your failing code identifying clearly where it fails

Comment: Edited Sir please guide me Steve Sir........

Comment: How did you set your `My.Settings`?

Comment: To save email and password.....

Comment: @PakDefndr No ***how*** did you set them? You can't just go and use some random setting without declaring it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot, it looks like you haven't set your application's Settings.

Project Settings can be set by navigating to **Project Properties > Settings**:

[image]

When this has been done, they can be referenced and modified by using `My.Settings.[setting]`, and saving them with `My.Settings.Save()`, as per se:

```
My.Settings.Username = "Foo"
My.Settings.Password = "Bar"
My.Settings.Save()
```

You can add any `My.Settings` property you want, but however you must ensure you choose the correct Type for your data.

---

Another [question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440039/how-to-use-cfg-and-saving-options-of-a-program/27440713#27440713) may aid you in this respect, to quote:

> A `User` setting creates new settings for each user account the
>   application is run under, the `Application` setting makes it so that the
>   settings are global and affects everyone regardless of what privileges
>   they hold in the system.
>
> There are also differences to how the settings are saved:
>
> **Application:** Saves in the `[project name].config` file
>
> **User:** Saves in
>   `<c:\Documents>\<username>\[LocalSettings\]ApplicationData\<companyname>\<appdomainname>_<eid>_<hash>\<version>`
>
> You [can see more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691858/where-are-my-settings-saved-in-vb-2010-net) on where the settings are saved.

Comment: @PakDefndr No, that's not how this website works. Please give feedback on whether what I provided worked for you.

Comment: Cyber monkey bro thanks this pic is a solution i did it one more thing i want to know how to add bcc mail in it

Comment: @PakDefndr Please click the green tick next to the voting buttons, to signify that this is the answer.