# Why are my application settings retrieving different values to the ones I expect?

Tags: app-config, configurationmanager

I have inherited an application which uses the configuration manager class to store and retrieve settings. In the app.config class there is custom section group "userSettings" which includes a "Server" property.

In the app.config file this value is defined as "a14". In Settings.Designer.vb the default is specified as "a5" yet when I try to access My.Settings.Server it brings back the value "a10", which is a value I previously used in the app.config file.

Not having much experience with the configuration manager, I am at a loss to determine where it is retrieving this value from and what I need to change so that it retrieves the correct server value.

For brevity, I have removed other settings from the code sample.

app.config:

```
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="WorkstationApp.My.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
```

...

```
<userSettings>
    <WorkstationApp.My.MySettings>
        <setting name="Server" serializeAs="String">
            <value>a14</value>
        </setting>
    </WorkstationApp.My.MySettings>
</userSettings>
```

Settings.Designer.vb:

```
    <Global.System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute(),  _
     Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
     Global.System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("a5")>  _
    Public Property Server() As String
        Get
            Return CType(Me("Server"),String)
        End Get
        Set
            Me("Server") = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Application code: (server is being set to "a10", but I want it to have the app.config value of "a14").

```
Dim Server As String = My.Settings.Server
```

Comment: Try deleting the project's `Bin` and `Debug` folders?  One of these may contain an old version of `app.config`.

Comment: Sorry, still coming back with a10. Good suggestion though.

Comment: I have resolved this issue by starting the application, changing the value of the settings and then using my.settings.save to save the new values. I still would like to know where it was writing this data though.

Comment: Difficult to guess without seeing all of the code. Could be that during initialize the setter executes more than once. I would set a breakpoint on the setter to confirm. If it breaks a second time on the setter, check the call stack at that point.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I was expecting the wrong thing (well duh). I had these settings set as User settings, which are stored in the /appdata/ folder and had nothing to do with the app.config file at all.

The user config file had been set with the initial values and had never been modified subsequently with a My.Settings.Save. More details in this answer: [Where are My.Settings saved in VB 2010 .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691858/where-are-my-settings-saved-in-vb-2010-net)