# I get an error about config on my application at start

Tags: vb.net

I have an application that is working ok but in one machine with Windows XP I get an error at start, it seem like the application can't access system configuration. (My.Settings?)

It was working ok until yesterday.
I don't know what the user do to get this error; Maybe deleted the configuration file? I don't know where is located.

I try reinstalling and get the same error.

Comment: Maybe because Windows XP is long expired! What is the error message?

Comment: The short message "Can't access system configuration", the long is a stacktrace and I read something about MySettings.

Comment: does the file "<YourAppName>.exe.conifhg" exist in the folder next to your executable?

Comment: No. I read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691858/where-are-my-settings-saved-in-vb-2010-net and decide to manually delete the config folder and reinstall and now is working again. I don't understand what happened, the config files was inside those folders, one for every version that was installed.

Comment: Perhaps the config of the current version was corrupt/malformed?