# Application settings value never erase when vb.net software uninstall

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

In my project setup file install in my and other pc ,

in my project settings value are charged at running time it will save change in setting value but I am uninstall my software it will not erase setting data it store previous data so

Application settings field value can not eraser at uninstall time after  reinstall software this value are irritating on software configuration time

Comment: An uninstaller will only remove files that it installed, and only if those files are identical to the ones it installed. If the settings file was modified after installation, the installer can't tell if it's safe to remove it or not and therefore won't do so. (Users get really angry when you delete files they've created and put in the wrong folder by mistake, or destroy hours of their work by deleting when they uninstall/reinstall your software. It also presents a legal liability for you if it does so in many jurisdictions, including the US.)

Answer (score 0):

You application stores it's settings in a totally separate folder, the ApplicationData folder.  Depending on how exactly you uninstall the program, you usualy still have to manualy erase the folder to remove these settings after an uninstall.

Depending on which operating system you have the location of the folder could differ.

Take a look at [These Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691858/where-are-my-settings-saved-in-vb-2010-net)